# Ng-Include, Prototypical Inheritance and Objects Vs Primitives -- Weird Behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My overall question is: is this expected behavior?

I have a demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RMGKxVMsbO6tOI1ftftQ?p=preview

I have a string, a bool, a integer printed three times in three different scopes.

First in the MainCtrl controller's scope's version of these properties.

There there is second instances of SubController's instances of these values, including printing the integer from it's inherited parent.

The "Mess With Values" button will add to the integer, toggle the boolean, and string append the strings.

What I think is weird:

1) Before you click the "new child scope"'s button, changes to the parents integer and other primitives is reflected in the template for ng-included instance of subcontroller. Once you click the ng-included's button and try to set the parents values, not only are the values not updated in the first (parent's) but further updates to the value (using the 2nd button) are not seen.

2) The ng-included cannot update the parents values, both primitives and the object property. The non ng-included one can update the parents primitives values just fine. Why is this?

I've read [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) and while it's very awesome, I didn't quite see an example that explains this odditiy, especially the access to the parent's properties working BEFORE an attempt to access them.

Thanks for your assistance SO community. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that ng-include inserts an extra $scope between the child and the parent. So when your non ng-included portion updates the $parent, it is updating the parent you expect. However, when you update $parent from the ng-included portion, you are updating a $scope that isn't obviously visible.

You can see this by adding `console.log($scope.parent)` inside the `testFunc()` and expanding up the `$parent` hierarchy.

Comment: Why doesn't the ng-included portion update the parent that HAS the property. I thought it traveled up the chain for reading a property, why not also for writing?

Comment: You need to read about using the `.` with angular scopes. http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: This article is exactly the info I need. Thanks!